# Obtain values from Laravel Controller and display in Vue

Tags: laravel, forms, vue.js

In a Laravel 8 view, I have a Vue component with a form.

```
<contact-form-component contact-store-route="{{ route('contact.store') }}">
</contact-form-component>
```

ContactFormController.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="success">
            SUCCESS!
        </div>
        <div v-if="error">
            ERROR!
        </div>

        <div v-show="!success">
        <form
                @submit.prevent="storeContact"
                method="POST"
                novalidate="novalidate"
                @keydown="clearError"
        >

        <input type="text" name="fullname" v-model="formData.fullname" />
        <input type="text" name="email" v-model="formData.email" />
        <input type="text" name="phone" v-model="formData.phone"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>   
</template>

<script>
import Form from "./Form.vue";

export default {
    mixins: [Form],
    props: {
        contactStoreRoute: String,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            formData: {
                fullname: null,
                lname: null,
                email: null,
                phone: null,
                message: null,
            },
        };
    },
    methods: {
        storeContact() {
            this.post(this.contactStoreRoute, this.formData);
        },
    },
    mounted() {},
};
</script>
```

Form.vue

```
<template></template>

<script>
import FormErrors from "./FormErrors.vue";
export default {
    name: "Form",
    mixins: [FormErrors],
    data() {
        return {
            success: false,
            error: false,
            errorMessage: "",
        };
    },
    methods: {
        post(url, data) {
            this.success = false;
            this.error = false;
            axios
                .post(url, data)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.onSuccess(res.data.message);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    if (error.response.status == 422) {
                        this.setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
                    } else {
                        this.onFailure(error.response.data.message);
                    }
                });
        },
        get(url, data) {
            this.success = false;
            this.error = false;
            axios
                .get(url, data)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.onSuccess(res.data.message);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    if (error.response.status == 422) {
                        this.setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
                    } else {
                        this.onFailure(error.response.data.message);
                    }
                });
        },
        onSuccess(message) {
            this.reset();
            this.success = true;
        },
        onFailure(message) {
            this.error = true;
            this.errorMessage = message;
        },
        reset() {
            this.clearAllErrors();
            for (let field in this.formData) {
                this.formData[field] = null;
            }
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

FormErrors.vue

```
<template></template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "FormErrors",
    data() {
        return {
            errors: {},
        };
    },
    methods: {
        setErrors(errors) {
            this.errors = errors;
        },
        hasError(fieldName) {
            return fieldName in this.errors;
        },
        getError(fieldName) {
            return this.errors[fieldName][0];
        },
        clearError(event) {
            Vue.delete(this.errors, event.target.name);
        },
        clearAllErrors() {
            this.errors = {};
        },
    },
    computed: {
        hasAnyError() {
            return Object.keys(this.errors).length > 0;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

When the form is submitted, a laravel post route is called and the information is stored in the database.

```
Route::post('/contact/store', [ContactController::class,'store'])->name('contact.store');
```

After this, the Vue component now hides the form and displays a "success" message. So far, everything works great.

Now, I would like to add a step. Instead of success message, I want to obtain the last id entered in the db and show a new form with a hidden field last_id. I am unsure of how to obtain this information from the controller.

It would be a continuation of the previous form, but I do not want to gather all the data at once, I want it in steps. Now, it is also important to gather data from the first form, and if the user quits after the first form that is fine, no problem, but if the user continues with the second form I need to "link" it to the previous form through the last_id.

I think that I am not approaching this problem correctly, maybe I need to change the logic of what I am doing.

Adding last_id to ContactController return:

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'fullname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required',
        ]);

        $contact_form = Contact::create($data);

        $last_id = $contact_form->id;

        return [
            //how do I "send" this to the Vue component?
            'last_id' => $last_id
        ];
    }
}
```

This would be the "second step" form using the last ID. It would have it's own post route.

```
<h4>Your form has been successfully submitted, now please give us more info that will be linked to the previous form:</h4>
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="last_id" value="{HOW_TO_GET_THE_LAST_ID_HERE?}" />
<textarea name="message" required></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON response: 
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#json-responses

You can return the id in your Controller for example like this:

```
return response()
            ->json(['last_id' => $last_id])
```

You will be able to get the value from the response object of the post call

```
.then((res) => {
      //get the id from the response
      this.last_id = (res.data.last_id);
})
```